# SQL - One to Many join with left outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2008-r2

SQL Server 2008 r2

I have 2 tables

**Table 1**

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
123   08   1    1
123   08   1    1
123   08   2    1
```

**Table 2**

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
123   08   6
```

Table 1 is the main column so most of the data comes from this table and it must be a LEFT OUTER JOIN on to Table2 because Table1 has values(col1, col2) that dont always return values in TABLE2 and should appear as NULLS.

My query is

```
SELECT
  a.Col2,
  SUM(a.Col3),
  SUM(a.Col4),
  SUM(b.Col3)
FROM
  Table 1 a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 b
    ON a.col1 = b.col1 AND a.col2 = b.col2
GROUP BY a.Col2
```

This would return 08, 4, 3, 18

I would want this to return 08, 4, 3, 6

Because Table 2 joins on 3 rows it then triples the SUM value for b.Col3

What would be the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to sum across the records, you can add `b.Col3` to the GROUP BY:

```
SELECT
  a.Col2,
  SUM(a.Col3),
  SUM(a.Col4),
  b.Col3
FROM
  Table 1 a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 b
    ON a.col1 = b.col1 AND a.col2 = b.col2
GROUP BY a.Col2, b.Col3
```

Comment: This worked well as I created a view and summed the contents of Table2 so then joined on the new view and used the group by with Col3, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. This will also take care if you have two records in table2 for same col1 and col2.

```
SELECT 
a.Col2,
SUM(a.Col3),
SUM(a.Col4),
MAX(b.Col3) FROM
Table 1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select col1, col2, sum(col3) as col3 from Table2 group by col1, col2) b ON a.col1 = b.col1 AND a.col2 = b.col2
GROUP BY
a.Col2
```

Answer (score 0):

If the result you want in the fourth column is not a sum, then it's not clear what you *do* want.  If you can rely on all rows of each group to have the same value in that column (which they will in your example, but might not with different data), and if *that's* the value you want, then you can use this:

```
SELECT
  a.Col2,
  SUM(a.Col3),
  SUM(a.Col4),
  MIN(b.Col3)
FROM
  Table 1 a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 b
    ON a.col1 = b.col1 AND a.col2 = b.col2
GROUP BY a.Col2
```

You could also use `MAX()` instead of `MIN()`, of course.